# Web scraping returns empty character

Tags: r, web-scraping, rstudio, is-empty

I am attempting to put together a real estate dataset, however when I try and extract the text from the website, for example the names of the places, it returns a variable with the characters empty.

```
link = "https://www.funda.nl/en/koop/amsterdam/"
page = read_html(link)

name <- page %>% html_nodes(".search-result__header-title") %>% html_text()
```

Any advice on how to get past this?

Comment: Have you checked what the contents of page after reading the link are? I get `[3] "We houden ons platform graag veilig en spamvrij. Daarom moeten we soms verifiëren dat onze bezoekers echte mensen zijn."`

Comment: `name` is not empty if I run the code, but contains 15 elements containing addresses.

Comment: that's strange. When i run the code i get none of the outputs that you received. Is there maybe a setting that needs to be changed when web scraping or?